# what is cross compilation or debugging on the target?

Tags: linux, operating-system, embedded-linux

I am writing a program on host computer (using eclipse ide) on linux operating sytem. I want to run this program on the Linux RTOS (which is my target) ?? could anyone tell me is it cross compiling or debugging in my case ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a C program (eclipse IDE) on the linux target?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838920/how-to-run-a-c-program-eclipse-ide-on-the-linux-target)

Comment: Eclipse IDE - OK, but which programming language do you use? Did you try installing Linux RTOS on virtual machine and running the compiled program there?

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you build an application for a target that is a different architecture from your build machine, you need to perform cross compilation. e.g. you want to develop code on your Linux host, which runs on an x86 architecture, and you want to run your application on your embedded Linux RTOS, which runs on an ARM system.

Even when debugging (where you connect the host and target via a cable and are able to run/step/halt code, view memory, etc.) the code is first cross compiled so that it may run on the target.

Basically, anytime your application runs on the target board (including debugging), you must first cross compile.